# PauseTransition Implementation event syntax

Tags: java, event-handling, transition

I am struggling to get a pauseTransition that makes use of .setOnFinished().

I am new to dealing with javafx events and so suspect that my issue may lie here.

My original error, I proceeded to encounter many more whilst attempting to fix it, was as follows:
Code:

> pt.setOnFinished(
>   event -> {
>   image=otherImage;
>                 }
>                                   );

Resulting message:

> illegal expression
>
> illegal expression
>
> illegal expression

If possible can the individual kind enough to give me an answer explain what the " event-> " does?

Comment: The `->` syntax is explained in [Syntax of Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax).  A comparison of the lambda syntax vs an Anonymous Inner Class is defined in [Lambda Expressions in GUI Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#lambda-expressions-in-gui-applications).

Comment: As to why you get an `illegal expression` message, I don't know as I cannot replicate it.  If you want assistance with that, provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and *full* stack trace in your question.